# Install Porteus Kiosk on RPi

Tags: kiosk

Does anyone know if there is any way to install [Porteus Kiosk](http://porteus-kiosk.org) on a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

From your linked page:

> ARM devices are currently not supported by Porteus Kiosk although this
>   may change in the future.

So it's not possible now, but may be at some point.